# Linq-style select statement in Javascript

Tags: javascript, linq

In Linq I can write

```
var ids = entities.Select(e=>e.ID);
```

Is it possible to write in Javascript in one line, with the same clarity ?

No loops, please.

Thanks

Maxim

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using [Underscore.js](http://underscorejs.org/), yes.

```
var ids = _.filter(entities, function(e) { return e.ID });
```

In fact, this use of anonymous functions (aka lambda expressoins) which C# adopted recently with LINQ is central to the way JavaScript is used in most cases.

There's a special-case in underscore too:

```
var ids = _.pluck(entities, "ID");
```

Answer (score 1):

You can define this method as this:

```
Array.prototype.select=function(selector) {
  var result = [];
  for(var i=0;i<this.length;i++) result.push(selector(this[i]));
  return result;
}
```

Then use it afterwards anywhere like this:

```
var ids = entities.select(function(e) {return e.ID;} );
```

JavaScript 1.7 now supports generators (thus, `yield` keyword), so you can write the select method like a generator, for it to be as close to the .NET version as possible.

```
Array.prototype.select=function(selector) {
  for(var i=0;i<this.length;i++) yield selector(this[i]);
}
```

But I'm suspicious to generators. I haven't played with them to see how they behave in JS. And older browsers won't support them, so explore, use at your own risk.

If you want to try [TypeScript](http://www.typescriptlang.org/), the syntax will be even closer to that of .NET. Something like this:

```
ids:number[] = entities.select((e) => {return e.ID;} );
```

Answer (score 1):

if you are using the VS development tools you may use [JSLinq](http://jslinq.codeplex.com/) or you can simple get the .js files from the example.

after install it you can do something like

```
var myList = [
            {id:1,FirstName:"Chris",LastName:"Pearson"},
            {id:2,FirstName:"Kate",LastName:"Johnson"},
            {id:3,FirstName:"Josh",LastName:"Pearson"},
            {id:4,FirstName:"John",LastName:"Pearson"},
            {id:5,FirstName:"Steve",LastName:"Pearson"}
            ];

var ids = JSLINQ(myList)
            .Where(function(item){ return item.LastName.match(/Pear.*/))})
            .Select(function(item){return item.id;});
```